# Why only initializer list can be used here to intialize the class properly?

Tags: c++

this code would crash due to out of bounds access when private member variables are initialized within the constructor,

but run smoothly when initialized using initializer list.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class PARVUS {
private:
  vector<vector<int>> vec2d;
  int vecWidth;

public:
  PARVUS(int);
  void addVecMember(int, int);

  vector<vector <int>> getVec() const { return vec2d; }
  int getVecWidth() const { return vecWidth; }
};

/* The following segment when REPLACED by initializer list approach, would not cause program to crash.
  FAULTY CODE BEGIN
*/

PARVUS::PARVUS(int width) {
  vecWidth = width;
  cout << "using width [" << width << "] to initialize object." << endl;
  vector<vector<int>> vec2d(vecWidth, vector<int>(0));
  cout << "vec size in constructor: " << vec2d.size() << endl;
}

/* FAULTY CODE ENDS */


void PARVUS::addVecMember(int i, int j) 
{
  cout << "Pushing back c: " << j << endl;
  cout << "Vec size in addVecMember: " << (this->vec2d).size() << endl;
  this->vec2d[i].push_back(j);
}

int main() {
  PARVUS t1(2);
  t1.addVecMember(1,1);
  t1.addVecMember(1,3);
  t1.addVecMember(1,5);

  cout << "Elements in vector at index[1] :" << endl;
  for (auto x : t1.getVec())
    for (auto y : x) {
      cout << y << ' ';
    }
   cout << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

If I initialize using initializer list like down below, it runs without crash.

just replace FAULTY CODE SEGMENT with following:

```
PARVUS::PARVUS(int width ) 
: vec2d(width, vector<int>(0)), vecWidth(width) 
{ cout << "vec size in constructor: " << vec2d.size() << endl;}
```

Through the test prints one can observe the `vec2d` was never initialized properly when not using initializer list.

```
using width [2] to initialize object. 
vec size in constructor: 2
Pushing back c: 1 
Vec size in addVecMember: 0
....segmentation fault....
```

why?

Comment: `vector<vector<int>> vec2d` declares a local variable, it doesn't initialise the member variable with the same name

Comment: @AlanBirtles , thanks for pointing that out,  if I had to initialize vec2d inside constructor body, is there a syntax for that?

Comment: @Sajuuk If you don't use the initializer list, your `vec2d` would be default initialized as an empty vector. Then you would either `push_back` elements manually, or create a second vector and copy it to `vec2d`